# How to Add Fractions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for a way to add fractions stored as 1/3, 2/3 or 1/6 etc
in SQL Server.

The output should be in fractions only as 1/4 + 2/4 = 3/4
or 1/4 + 1/4 +  1/4 + 1/4 = 1

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store fractions, it stores floating point, decimal or integer values. This is likely a job for your presentation layer, which can convert the numerical value to a fraction value for display purposes. For example, in Excel, using the format `# ?/?` on the values `0.25`, `0.33333`, and `0.125` would display `1/4`, `1/3` and `1/8` respectively.

Comment: This doesn't look like a SQL thing - you'd be better off converting the decimal to a fraction in another layer (i.e. C#/VB/whatever you're using.

Comment: @Anurag Most languages don't have fractions so where does `1/3` come from and how is it stored?

Comment: Do you mean the fractions are stored in *varchar* columns? As "strings"? Like `create table fractions(fraction varchar(20)); insert fractions values("1/4");`?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the data types and table structure, I am assuming that the fractions are stored in a `VARCHAR` field. Here is a short script that shows how to add two fractions that are stored in a `VARCHAR` field. The procedure is to parse the fractions into individual numerators and denominators, do a brute force addition by finding a common denominator that is the product of the two denominators, and then to reduce the fraction you find the greatest common divisor (GCD) using the Euclidean Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) of the resulting numerator and resulting denominator and then divide each by the GCD. The explanation is probably worse than just seeing the sample script.

```sql
DECLARE @f1 VARCHAR(5) = '1/4';
DECLARE @f2 VARCHAR(5) = '1/2';

-- declare variables for the numerators and denominators
DECLARE @n1 INT, @n2 INT, @d1 INT, @d2 INT, @resultN INT, @resultD INT;

-- find the individual numerators
SELECT @n1 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@f1, 1, CHARINDEX('/', @f1, 1) - 1) AS INT);
SELECT @n2 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@f2, 1, CHARINDEX('/', @f2, 1) - 1) AS INT);

-- find the individual denominators
SELECT @d1 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@f1, CHARINDEX('/', @f1, 1) + 1, LEN(@f1) - CHARINDEX('/', @f1, 1)) AS INT);
SELECT @d2 = CAST(SUBSTRING(@f2, CHARINDEX('/', @f2, 1) + 1, LEN(@f2) - CHARINDEX('/', @f2, 1)) AS INT);

-- a common denominator is the product of the two denominators
SELECT @resultD = @d1 * @d2;
-- the numerator is the sum of the numerators multiplied by the other denominator
SELECT @resultN = @n1 * @d2 + @n2 * @d1;

-- here is the sum without reducing the fraction
SELECT CONCAT(@resultN, '/', @resultD) AS [Unreduced Result];

-- to reduce, find the GCD of the @resultN and @resultD and divide each by the GCD
DECLARE @a INT, @b INT, @t INT;
SELECT @a = ABS(@resultN);
SELECT @b = ABS(@resultD);
WHILE (@b <> 0) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @t = @b;
    SELECT @b = @a % @b;
    SELECT @a = @t;
END
-- at this point @a is the GCD
SELECT @resultN = @resultN / @a;
SELECT @resultD = @resultD / @a;

SELECT CONCAT(@resultN, '/', @resultD) AS [Reduced Result];
```

You can easily adapt this technique and turn it into a function - just make sure to do appropriate error checking for `NULL` values and whole numbers.